# Justify menu with css

Tags: html, css

Im working on menu, which is text justified. To make this working, I add an new line. the problem is that it should be zero pixels. However, it's breaking layout

JS fiddle to see it in work
https://jsfiddle.net/z1qsL739/1/

```
<div class="registration-menu">
  <ul class="reg-menu-list">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">some </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some</a></li>
    <div class="justify-fix"></div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Css

```
.registration-menu{
    background: white;
    border-top: 4px solid green;
    border-bottom: 4px solid green;
}

.reg-menu-list{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 0em;
    color: green;
    font-size: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    .justify-fix{
      width: 100%;
        line-height: 0em;
        height: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        content: ' ';
    }
    li{
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 1em;
        font-size: 18px;
        &.active{
            background: #fde8be;
            border-top: 4px solid #ffb642;
            border-bottom: 4px solid #ffb642;
            margin: -4px 0 -4px 0;
        }
        a{
            padding: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        &:hover{
            @include transition(all .4s ease);
            background: #fde8be;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using SASS? because otherwise you can't nest CSS classes.

Comment: This looks like it's working perfectly. What exactly is it breaking?

Comment: Of course it's invalid HTML, you can't have a div as a child of a `ul` https://jsfiddle.net/z1qsL739/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by adding the following rules, `height: 46px;` to the `.registration-menu` and `padding: 4px 0;` to the `.reg-menu-list`

```
.registration-menu {
    background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid green;
    border-top: 4px solid green;
    height: 46px;
}
.reg-menu-list {
    color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    list-style: outside none none;
    padding: 4px 0;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `div` is not allowed inside a list as a direct child. A modern and straightforward way to go is using `flexbox` positioning, e.g.

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpbWJk?editors=0100

Comment: Not my DV but this is working fine as is (even though the HTML is invalid)...it's not clear what the OP's issue actually is.

Comment: I guess he want to obtain the same effect but without the div

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the div at all, use a pseudo-element

```css
.registration-menu {
  background: white;
  border-top: 4px solid green;
  border-bottom: 4px solid green;
}
.reg-menu-list {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0em;
  color: green;
  font-size: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.reg-menu-list::after {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0em;
  height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  content: ' ';
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: pink;
}
li.active {
  background: #fde8be;
  border-top: 4px solid #ffb642;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ffb642;
  margin: -4px 0 -4px 0;
}
a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
a:hover {
  @include transition(all .4s ease);
  background: #fde8be;
}
```

```html
<div class="registration-menu">
  <ul class="reg-menu-list">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">some </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">some</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">some</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">some </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">some</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">some</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

remove `display: inline-block` from `.reg-menu-list`

Comment: An explanation would be helpful. What is the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.